# In Django, how can I understand include() function?

Tags: python, django

I have started learning Django, I'm not sure what the **include()** function means.

Here is ***mysite/urls.py***. - **project**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Here is ***polls/urls.py***. - **app in project**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

From django document, **include()** function was described as follows.

> Whenever Django encounters include(), it chops off whatever part of the URL ***matched up to that point*** and sends the ***remaining string*** to the included URLconf for further processing.

I'm not sure what is **that point**, what is **remaining string**.

In case of the example above, what is **remining string**, what is **url** strings which was chopped off?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For example, from this URL:

```
polls/5/results
```

the URL rule:

```
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
```

chops off the `polls/` part of URL and sends the remaining string after `polls/`, whatever it might be, for example (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views) more):

```
5/results/
```

to urls from the poll app's urls.py, where it will then be mapped to a view based on the URL rules defined in this file

Comment: Hi, doru. thanks for your help. Would you tell me what does **name** mean? - *url(r'^$', views.index, **name**='index')*

Comment: @YuiryKozlenko for easy access an url you can give it a human readable name: `name="easy-human-readable-name-for-this-url"` and after that you can access it by name, for ex in template `{% url "easy-human-readable-name-for-this-url" %}`

Answer (score 5):

Whenever it will encounter any url with `/polls` then it will include all the urls of polls app.

**Example:**

If you type `/polls/hey`

Then as soon as it sees `/polls` it will go to polls urls file and later it will search for:

`hey/` matching over there.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say there is one more entry in your polls/urls.py like 

`url(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive),`

here year is the query string parameter. so your url will look like

**/polls/articles/2007** so in this case **/polls/articles/** will matched up and 2007 will pass to year_archive method

Answer (score 1):

In your example there is no chopped string, the URL comes back as simply `polls/`, but when you have another url such as `'^new$'` then that url is being chopped, merged with `polls/` and it returns `polls/new`, hope this makes sense..